# Web Platform Installer - Specific Application Pool in IIS7.0

Tags: iis, application-pool, web-platform-installer

I'm making a zip package to be uploaded to the MS web gallery.
There is no SQL database, so manifest.xml looks pretty simple...

```
<MSDeploy.iisApp>
   <iisApp path="test_app"/>
</MSDeploy.iisApp>
```

as well as parameters.xml

```
<parameters>
  <parameter
    name="Application Path"
    description="Full site path where you would like to install your application"
    defaultValue="test_app"
    tags="iisapp">
    <parameterEntry
      type="ProviderPath"
      scope="iisapp"
      match="test_app"
      />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

On IIS 6.0 it gets deployed properly.
But on IIS 7.0 it always has app pool targeted to asp.net 2.0.
I need a default, asp.net 4.0 pool.

If I specify a new pool in appPoolConfig section of manifest.xml file, all the pools in IIS 7.0 that existed before installation are removed, which corrupts currently installed applications.

Is there a way to tell WebPI that I want my test_app be running in existing Default ASP.NET 4.0 Application Pool?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding the following lines to your custom WPI feed:

```
<dependency>
    <or>
        <dependency>
            <productId>NETFramework4</productId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <productId>NETFramework45</productId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <productId>NETFX4</productId>
        </dependency>
    </or>
</dependency>
```

But as far I know, the WPI will create new application pool (with .NET 4.0) that name based on your iisApp path provider. So we can't add to existing application pool.